# Chrome --load-extension doesn't work on some machines

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to load unpack extension using command line flag --load-extension. 
I'm using one chrome profile. The syntax for query is following:

*chrome --load-extension="C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\unpackExtensionFolder"*

Inside unpackExtensionFolder there is manifest.JSON and all sources. 
This command doesn't work on few PCs in office, but it works on the rest of them, and successfully loads the extension (Chrome version is the same on all machines - 31, extension that we are trying to load is the same).

Discovered:

1. Doesn't depend on chrome profiles amount
2. Doesn't depend on developer mode on/off

***The question is why? And what could have influence on this?***

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this was plugin inside manifest file, seems that chrome was not able to load extension with plugin declarated in it. Works fine after removing plugin section.